# Checking type of generic class

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface:

```
public interface IValidator<E extends IEntity>
{
    void validate(final E entity);
}
```

I would like to create a ValidatorService class, something like this:

```
public class ValidatorService
{
    private List<IValidator<IEntity>> validators;


    public void validate(IEntity e)
    {
        for(IValidator<IEntity> validator : this.validators)
        {
            //if( instanceof )???
            validator.validate(e);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make sure that validators are applied only to their corresponding classes (please see '???' in code)? I.e.: if we have entity of type EntityA, then only validator IValidator will be invoked? I think I lack some knowledge of generics.. Thanks

Comment: java will throw an exception if one of the validators does not implements IValidator

Comment: All validators will implement IValidator, but then only some of them should be run for certain IEntities...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to type erasure, this is not possible.

Instead, you can add a `Class<E> getEntityClass()` method to the interface.

Comment: hi, thanks for this. I've done how you suggest, but now I got following problem: 'Class entityClass = validator.getEntityClass(); if(e instanceof entityClass)' error: "entityClass cannot be resolved to a type" How should I use getEntityClass method ? Thx

Comment: @fazomisiek: Since you have a `Class` instance rather than a type, you should call `isInstanceOf()`.